# struts 2 iterator perform slow

Tags: struts2, ognl

I am using strut2 in my project in which in jsp pages i have to show list of items greater than 500. I have used following tags.

```
          <s:iterator value="list" status="status" > 
             <s:property value="%{val1}" />
             <s:property value="%{val2}" />
             <s:property value="%{val3}" />
             <s:property value="%{map[val]}" />
        </s:iterator>
```

when the list size is large, it iterates very slowly. while iterating, i am also retrieving values from maps.

I am not able to find what is exactly happening . what should i do to iterate fast or improve performance of iterator.

Thanks

Comment: which version of struts2 and OGNL you are using??

Comment: struts2 2.0.1 but don't no about OGNL version .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using very old version of Struts2(2.0.1) and in that case might be using old version of OGNL which was having really some bad performance issues.

Suggest you to first go through some performance tips.
[performance-tuning](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/performance-tuning.html)

next step is to manually  update the version of ognl you're using in your own
app in that case you might have to add javassist jar.

Go through the Struts2 mailing list discussion thread for similar issue.

[Slow-performance-with-Struts2](http://struts.1045723.n5.nabble.com/Slow-performance-with-Struts2-td3487150.html)

Comment: Thanks for links I found struts2 version is 2.1.8.1 and OGNL version is 2.7.3 . so need to switch latest version. but is it possible to do something in same version ?

Comment: If its allowed for you can upgrade OGNL jar